# Cant get rid of vspaces after align environment

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I have the next document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paper=a5paper,
    inner=0cm, outer=0cm, top=0cm, bottom=0cm, 
    bindingoffset=0cm, 
    textwidth=\textwidth, textheight=\textheight, 
    includehead=false, includefoot=false, landscape, twoside}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\cheattitle}[1]{%
    {\sf \slshape \center \hspace{\fill}#1\hspace{\fill}}%
}

\begin{document}
\smallj

\cheattitle{Основні правила диференціювання}
\begin{align*}
    &(u+v)'=u'+v' & & (u-v)'=u'-v' & & (uv)'=u'v+uv' &  & (Cu)'=Cu'\\
    & (uvw)'=u'vw+uv'w+uvw' & & \left(\frac{u}{v}\right)' =\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2},\ v\neq 0 & & \left(\frac{C}{v}\right)'=-C\frac{v'}{v^2},\ v\neq 0 & & \left(\frac{u}{C}\right)'=\frac{1}{C}u'\\
\end{align*}
\cheattitle{Таблиця похідних}
\begin{align*}
    & C'=0 & & (u^n)'=nu^{n-1}u' & & \left(\sqrt{u}\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}u' & & \left(\frac{1}{u}\right)'=-\frac{1}{u^2}u' & & \left(a^u\right)'=a^u\ln a\cdot u' \\
    & (e^u)'=e^uu' & & \left(\log_au\right)'=\frac{1}{u\ln a} u' & & \left(\ln u\right)'=\frac{1}{u}u' & & \left(\sin u\right)'=\cos u\cdot u' & & \left(\cos u\right)'=-\sin u\cdot u'\\
    & \left(\tg u\right)' = \frac{1}{\cos^2u}u' & &\left(\ctg u\right)' = \frac{1}{\sin^2u}u' & & \left(\arcsin u\right)' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}u' & & \left(\arccos u\right)'= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} & & \left(\arcctg u\right)' = \frac{1}{i+u^2}u'\\
    & \left(\arcctg u\right)'=-\frac{1}{1+u^2}u' & & \left(\sh u\right)' = \ch u \cdot u' & & \left(\ch u\right)' = \sh u\cdot u' & & \left(\th u\right)' = \frac{1}{\ch^2u}u' & & \left(\cth u\right)' = -\frac{1}{\sh^2u}u'
\end{align*}
\cheattitle{Формула Тейлора}
\begin{align*}
    f(x) = f(0)+\frac{f'(0)}{1!}x+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2+\dots+\frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!}x^n+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

When typeset, it produces:

[image]

The problem is that I cant get rid of vertical spaces before "Таблиця похідних" and "Формула Тейлора". I am writing math cheatsheet and want it to fit as tight as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The final double-backslash directive in the first `align*` environment is causing the unwanted vertical whitespace. Delete it.

Comment: Oh my God. I do know about new line thing at the end of math environment but this one I have missed out. Thank You a lot!

Comment: It's not recommended to use `align` for single-line displays, although that's not the problem here.  Also, what's the purpose of `\center` in `\cheattitle`?  The two `\hspace{fill}`s are really doing the centering.

Comment: The formula for the derivative of the arccotangent is wrong! Beware! I didn't fix it in my answer, leaving the task to you.

Comment: @egreg Thank You! I accidentally wrote arcctg instead of arctg.

Comment: @VladyslavRehan And i instead of 1, but I see it fixed in the picture, not in the source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `\center`, but `\centering`, and make the spaces before and after displays to be zero. Since you follow this with `align`, `\noindent` is necessary. Don't leave blank lines after a `\cheattitle` line.

Also, don't leave trailing `\\` in `align`, which produces a blank line in the display.

I suggest `amsart` that directly supports `8pt`.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paper=a5paper,
  inner=0cm, outer=0cm, top=0cm, bottom=0cm, 
  bindingoffset=0cm, 
  includehead=false,
  includefoot=false,
  landscape,
  twoside
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\cheattitle}[1]{%
  \par{\sffamily\slshape\centering#1\par}\noindent\ignorespaces
}


\begin{document}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}

\cheattitle{Основні правила диференціювання}
\begin{align*}
    &(u+v)'=u'+v' && (u-v)'=u'-v' & & (uv)'=u'v+uv' &  & (Cu)'=Cu'\\
    & (uvw)'=u'vw+uv'w+uvw' & & \left(\frac{u}{v}\right)' =\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2},\ v\neq 0 & & \left(\frac{C}{v}\right)'=-C\frac{v'}{v^2},\ v\neq 0 & & \left(\frac{u}{C}\right)'=\frac{1}{C}u'
\end{align*}

\cheattitle{Таблиця похідних}
\begin{align*}
    & C'=0 & & (u^n)'=nu^{n-1}u' & & \left(\sqrt{u}\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}u' & & \left(\frac{1}{u}\right)'=-\frac{1}{u^2}u' & & \left(a^u\right)'=a^u\ln a\cdot u' \\
    & (e^u)'=e^uu' & & \left(\log_au\right)'=\frac{1}{u\ln a} u' & & \left(\ln u\right)'=\frac{1}{u}u' & & \left(\sin u\right)'=\cos u\cdot u' & & \left(\cos u\right)'=-\sin u\cdot u'\\
    & \left(\tg u\right)' = \frac{1}{\cos^2u}u' & &\left(\ctg u\right)' = \frac{1}{\sin^2u}u' & & \left(\arcsin u\right)' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}u' & & \left(\arccos u\right)'= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} & & \left(\arcctg u\right)' = \frac{1}{i+u^2}u'\\
    & \left(\arcctg u\right)'=-\frac{1}{1+u^2}u' & & \left(\sh u\right)' = \ch u \cdot u' & & \left(\ch u\right)' = \sh u\cdot u' & & \left(\th u\right)' = \frac{1}{\ch^2u}u' & & \left(\cth u\right)' = -\frac{1}{\sh^2u}u'
\end{align*}

\cheattitle{Формула Тейлора}
\begin{align*}
    f(x) = f(0)+\frac{f'(0)}{1!}x+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2+\dots+\frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!}x^n+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `article` with `fontsize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[fontsize=8pt]{fontsize}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paper=a5paper,
  inner=0cm, outer=0cm, top=0cm, bottom=0cm, 
  bindingoffset=0cm, 
  includehead=false,
  includefoot=false,
  landscape,
  twoside
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\cheattitle}[1]{%
  \par{\sffamily\slshape\centering#1\par}\noindent\ignorespaces
}


\begin{document}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}

\cheattitle{Основні правила диференціювання}
\begin{align*}
    &(u+v)'=u'+v' && (u-v)'=u'-v' & & (uv)'=u'v+uv' &  & (Cu)'=Cu'\\
    & (uvw)'=u'vw+uv'w+uvw' & & \left(\frac{u}{v}\right)' =\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2},\ v\neq 0 & & \left(\frac{C}{v}\right)'=-C\frac{v'}{v^2},\ v\neq 0 & & \left(\frac{u}{C}\right)'=\frac{1}{C}u'
\end{align*}

\cheattitle{Таблиця похідних}
\begin{align*}
    & C'=0 & & (u^n)'=nu^{n-1}u' & & \left(\sqrt{u}\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}u' & & \left(\frac{1}{u}\right)'=-\frac{1}{u^2}u' & & \left(a^u\right)'=a^u\ln a\cdot u' \\
    & (e^u)'=e^uu' & & \left(\log_au\right)'=\frac{1}{u\ln a} u' & & \left(\ln u\right)'=\frac{1}{u}u' & & \left(\sin u\right)'=\cos u\cdot u' & & \left(\cos u\right)'=-\sin u\cdot u'\\
    & \left(\tg u\right)' = \frac{1}{\cos^2u}u' & &\left(\ctg u\right)' = \frac{1}{\sin^2u}u' & & \left(\arcsin u\right)' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}u' & & \left(\arccos u\right)'= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} & & \left(\arcctg u\right)' = \frac{1}{i+u^2}u'\\
    & \left(\arcctg u\right)'=-\frac{1}{1+u^2}u' & & \left(\sh u\right)' = \ch u \cdot u' & & \left(\ch u\right)' = \sh u\cdot u' & & \left(\th u\right)' = \frac{1}{\ch^2u}u' & & \left(\cth u\right)' = -\frac{1}{\sh^2u}u'
\end{align*}

\cheattitle{Формула Тейлора}
\begin{align*}
    f(x) = f(0)+\frac{f'(0)}{1!}x+\frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2+\dots+\frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!}x^n+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Don't add `textwidth=\textwidth` and `textheight=\textheight`: they just result in annoying warnings.

Note also that `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is no longer necessary and that you should load (last) the T2A encoding for Cyrillic.

Finally, `\sf` has been deprecated for about 30 years.

Comment: Thanks for a corrections! This is priceless!

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
\newcommand{\cheattitle}[1]{%
    {\sf \slshape \center \vspace{-5mm} \hspace{\fill}#1\hspace{\fill}}%
}
```

to get tighter spacing. Play with the value, but -5 mm seems about the max.

Comment: why add vertical space with \center then immediately backspace???